# Session Time out while second ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using ASP .Net MVC 5, Razor View, VS 2013, MSSQL 2012

I choose a category number and click on choose button. With the CategoryID, an ajax call brings some data from server side.

For the first time clicking on the button, the procedure works fine. However, on the 2nd time clicking, there's no server side method calling & no error in ajaxrequest. It just returns a SessionTimeOut.

Here is my script:

```
$("#btnChoose").click(function (e) {
        //var brand = $("#brands input:radio:checked").val();
        //$("#output").html("<b>Your favorite mobile brand: </b>" + brand);
        $("#BrowseCategory").fadeOut(300);
        //e.preventDefault();
        var timer = setInterval(LoadeBayItemConditionAjax, 1000);
        function LoadeBayItemConditionAjax() {
            var selectedcategoryID = $("[id='hidCategoryID']").val();
            alert('hit');
            var URL = "@Url.Action("LoadCategoryFaced", "Listing")";
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ catId: selectedcategoryID }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                //async: false,
                //cache: false,
                timeout: 30000,
                success: function (data) {
                    var subSelect = $('#eBayItemCondition');
                    alert(subSelect);
                    subSelect.empty();
                    alert(data);
                    if (data != null || data != '')
                        $("#eBayItemConditionDiv").show();
                    else
                        $("#eBayItemConditionDiv").hide();
                    $.each(data, function (key, ddlCondition) {
                        $('select#eBayItemCondition').append($('<option/>', {
                            value: ddlCondition.Value,
                            text: ddlCondition.Name
                        }));
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    var status = AjaxErrorHandle(jqXHR, exception);
                    Notification("error", status, false);
                }
            });
            alert();
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

How can I prevent this sessionTimeOut? Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you saying that the server method is never called the second time? Or it is called but throws a session timeout ?

Comment: @Nilesh 2nd Time server method is "never" called. actually after 1st time, how much I try, the server method is never called. And AJAX request goes to `success` instead of error.

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? Try with chrome and see if the request is fired again.

Comment: use `setTimeout` - then you will not need to call `clearInerval`

Comment: @Nilesh I have tried IE, Chrome, Firefox & Safari. Same result.

Comment: @Igor I have used timeout : 30000 in ajax request. where to use setTimeout? Is it the reason for SessionTimeOut?

Comment: instead of setInterval you can use setTimeout

Comment: I see you have `//cache: false` commented. Did you try removing the comments?

Comment: @Nilesh I have tried cache & async. But same result in 2nd time.

Comment: @Igor I see. I read how it works. But its not solving my problem.